# Uniroot solution in R

Tags: r

I would like to find the root of the following function:

```
       x=0.5
       f <- function(y) ((1-pbeta(1-exp(-0.002926543
        *( 107.2592+y)^1.082618 *exp(0.04097536*(107.2592+y))),shape1=0.2640229,shape2=0.1595841)) -
(1-pbeta(1-exp(-0.002926543*(x)^1.082618 *exp(0.04097536*(x))),shape1=0.2640229,shape2=0.1595841))^2)

sroot=uniroot(f, lower=0, upper=1000)$root
```

> Error in uniroot(f, lower = 0, upper = 1000) :   f() values at end
>   points not of opposite sign

How can I solve the error?

Comment: The error message seems self explanatory. f(0) and f(1000) have the same sign so uniroot refuses to search that interval for a zero.

Comment: You can plot this function over the range 0 to 1000. `curve(f(x), 0, 1000)`. Doesn't look like it crosses 0.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**`uniroot()` and caution of its use**

[`uniroot`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/zeroin.c) is implementing the crude [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). Such method is much simpler that [(quasi) Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), but need stronger assumption to ensure the existence of a root: `f(lower) * f(upper) < 0`.

This can be quite a pain,as such assumption is a sufficient condition, but not a necessary one. In practice, if `f(lower) * f(upper) > 0`, it is still possible that a root exist, but since this is not of 100% percent sure, bisection method can not take the risk.

Consider this example:

```
# a quadratic polynomial with root: -2 and 2
f <- function (x) x ^ 2 - 4
```

Obviously, there are roots on `[-5, 5]`. But

```
uniroot(f, lower = -5, upper = 5)
#Error in uniroot(f, lower = -5, upper = 5) : 
#  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

In reality, the use of bisection method requires observation / inspection of `f`, so that one can propose a reasonable interval where root lies. In R, we can use `curve()`:

```
curve(f, from = -5, to = 5); abline(h = 0, lty = 3)
```

[image]

From the plot, we observe that a root exist in `[-5, 0]` or `[0, 5]`. So these work fine:

```
uniroot(f, lower = -5, upper = 0)
uniroot(f, lower = 0, upper = 5)
```

---

**Your problem**

Now let's try your function (I have split it into several lines for readability; it is also easy to check correctness this way):

```
f <- function(y) {
  g <- function (u) 1 - exp(-0.002926543 * u^1.082618 * exp(0.04097536 * u))
  a <- 1 - pbeta(g(107.2592+y), 0.2640229, 0.1595841)
  b <- 1 - pbeta(g(x), 0.2640229, 0.1595841)
  a - b^2
  }

x <- 0.5
curve(f, from = 0, to = 1000)
```

[image]

How could this function be a horizontal line? It can't have a root!

1. Check the `f` above, is it really doing the right thing you want? I doubt something is wrong with `g`; you might put brackets in the wrong place?
2. Once you get `f` correct, use `curve` to inspect a proper interval where there a root exists. Then use `uniroot`.

Comment: It's not true that uniroot uses bisection. It uses Brent's algorithm. In the R help file for uniroot, it states:

"Based on ‘zeroin.c’ in http://www.netlib.org/c/brent.shar."

Reading the documentation at netlib.org/c, we find the following information:

"file brent.shar
for Brent's univariate minimizer and zero finder.
by Oleg Keselyov <oleg@ponder.csci.unt.edu, oleg@unt.edu> May 23, 1991
ref G.Forsythe, M.Malcolm, C.Moler, Computer methods for mathematical computations."

Answer (score 5):

Try using a small interval but allow uniroot() to extend the interval:

```
uniroot(f, lower=0, upper=1, extendInt = "yes")$root
[1] -102.9519
```

Comment: Just want to tell people that `extendInt` does not always work so don't believe it does the magic. Taking the quadratic polynomial example in my answer for example, adding `extendInt = "yes"` gives another "iteration reaches limits" error. Because no matter how much you extend the interval, a sign change never happens.