# How to estimate x value from y value input after approxfun() in R

Tags: r

I would like to use `approxfun` or a similar method to estimate a function for a curve and then estimate what the `x` value of a point would be given a known `y` value.

Here is a simplified example.

```
y <- seq(from=1, to =10, by = 1)

x <-seq(from=0.1, to =1, by = 0.1)

fun <- approxfun(x,y)
```

I can approximate a `y` value given a known `x` value with the following command:

```
fun(0.65)
#[1] 6.5
```

But how can I do the reverse, i.e., solve `x` from `6.5 = approxfun(x)`?

Thanks for any help on my most likely dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analytical solution for linear interpolation (stable)

Suppose we have some `(x, y)` data. After a linear interpolation find all `x` such that the value of the interpolant equals `y0`.

```
## with default value y0 = 0, it finds all roots of the interpolant
RootLinearInterpolant <- function (x, y, y0 = 0) {
  if (is.unsorted(x)) {
     ind <- order(x)
     x <- x[ind]; y <- y[ind]
     }
  z <- y - y0
  ## which piecewise linear segment crosses zero?
  k <- which(z[-1] * z[-length(z)] < 0)
  ## analytically root finding
  xk <- x[k] - z[k] * (x[k + 1] - x[k]) / (z[k + 1] - z[k])
  xk
  }
```

A more complicated example and test.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sort(runif(10, 0, 10))
y <- rnorm(10, 3, 1)
y0 <- 2.5
xk <- RootLinearInterpolant(x, y, y0)
#[1] 3.375952 8.515571 9.057991

plot(x, y, "l"); abline(h = y0, lty = 2)
points(xk, rep.int(y0, length(xk)), pch = 19)
```

[image]

---

#### Numerical root finding for non-linear interpolation (not necessarily stable)

```
## suppose that f is an interpolation function of (x, y)
## this function finds all x, such that f(x) = y0
## with default value y0 = 0, it finds all roots of the interpolant
RootNonlinearInterpolant <- function (x, y, f, y0 = 0) {
  if (is.unsorted(x)) {
     ind <- order(x)
     x <- x[ind]; y <- y[ind]
     }
  z <- y - y0
  k <- which(z[-1] * z[-length(z)] < 0)
  nk <- length(k)
  xk <- numeric(nk)
  F <- function (x) f(x) - y0
  for (i in 1:nk) xk[i] <- uniroot(F, c(x[k[i]], x[k[i] + 1]))$root
  xk
  }
```

Try a natural cubic spline interpolation.

```
## cubic spline interpolation
f <- splinefun(x, y)
xk <- RootNonlinearInterpolant(x, y, f, y0)
#[1] 3.036643 8.953352 9.074306

curve(f, from = min(x), to = max(x))
abline(v = x, lty = 3)  ## signal pieces
abline(h = y0)
points(xk, rep.int(y0, length(xk)), pch = 20)
```

[image]

We see that that `RootNonlinearInterpolant` misses two crossover points on the 3rd piece.

`RootNonlinearInterpolant` relies on `uniroot` so the search is more restricted. Only if the sign of `y - y0` changes on adjacent knots a `uniroot` is called. Clearly this does not hold on the 3rd piece. *(Learn more about `uniroot` at [Uniroot solution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38961221/4891738).)*

Also note that `uniroot` only returns a single root. So the most stable situation is when the interpolant is monotone on the piece so a unique root exists. If there are actually multiple roots, `uniroot` would only find one of them.

Comment: My specific approach will rely on unique cases so this functions well for me! Many thanks!