# R: How do i find a parameter of beta function given values for the others?

Tags: r, function, math, parameters, probability

I have a variable Y with beta distribution : Beta(alpha,1/3).

I have to find the value of alpha such as :
P(Y <= 0.416) =0.2

for more details read my question in math stackexchange here : 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038125/beta-distribution-find-the-parameter-alpha-of-mathcalbe-alpha-frac1

I wrote this function (i supposed that x is alpha, the root of the function):

```
f=function(x){
pbeta(0.416,x,1/3)
}
```

and i tried to use uniroot:

```
uniroot(f,interval=c(0,5),tol=1e-5)
```

I din't understand this message: `Error in uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 5), tol = 1e-05) : f() values at end points not of opposite sign`.

I read here [Uniroot solution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961221/uniroot-solution-in-r) that this method method needs stronger assumption to ensure the existence of a root: f(lower) * f(upper) < 0; but i 
have a positive function and then i couldn't use this function!
Does an alternative function exist in R?
Can anyone suggest me the code, how to do find alpha with R?
Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: You need to apply uniroot to find the zero of `pbeta(0.416,x,1/3)-0.2`

Comment: Oh yes it's true! Thank you so much!