# Why are there inequalities in an R for loop using a vector and using ":"?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, variables, undefined

I have not a real problem but I don't quite get the difference in my code due to different writing schemes.

The situation is as follows:

I wrote a for loop that should insert certain values in my function. Before I did this I defined the parameters to insert. The code looks like this:

```
yield <- rep(1, nrow(timeseries1))
pc <- c(1:1265)
tc <- c(1:1265)
for(i in 1:1265){
  pc[i] <- timeseries1$`CoCo-Preis`[i]
  tc[i] <- timeseries1$t[i]
  yield[i] <- yield.to.call(ytc,p=pc[i],t=tc[i],c=5,N=100)
}
yield <- data.table(yield)
```

I simply want to tell the loop to insert the values from i=1 to i=1265 but what he does is to define i as 1264L. When i run another code AFTER I did the above he assigns i to 1265. The code is:

```
for(i in c(1,1265)){
  pc[i] <- timeseries1$`CoCo-Preis`[i]
  tc[i] <- timeseries1$t[i]
  yield[i] <- yield.to.call(ytc,p=pc[i],t=tc[i],c=5,N=100)
}
yield <- data.table(yield)
```

(Note the new interval as a vector) Now he especially offers me the right solution for the last value. But when I only run this second code it does not yield the right solutions at all apart from only the first value. So my workaround is to run both codes after each other but I want to know why I simply cannot run the second code only or why the first code stops before the last value.

I hope that anyone can help.

EDIT:

```
yield.to.call <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){
c <- c/f #new to adjust the coupon
if(t<92){t <- ((92-t)/(92-0))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+14)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+15)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+16)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+17)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+18)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+19)-p}}
else if(t<184){t <- ((184-t)/(184-92))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+14)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+15)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+16)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+17)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+18)-p}}
else if(t<275){t <- ((275-t)/(275-184))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+14)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+15)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+16)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+17)-p}}
else if(t<365){t <- ((365-t)/(365-275))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+14)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+15)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+16)-p}}
else if(t<457){t <- ((457-t)/(457-365))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+14)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+15)-p}}
else if(t<548){t <- ((548-t)/(548-457))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+14)-p}}
else if(t<639){t <- ((639-t)/(639-548))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+13)-p}}
else if(t<730){t <- ((730-t)/(730-639))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+12)-p}}
else if(t<821){t <- ((821-t)/(821-730))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+11)-p}}
else if(t<915){t <- ((915-t)/(915-821))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+10)-p}}
else if(t<1006){t <- ((1006-t)/(1006-915))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+9)-p}}
else if(t<1097){t <- ((1097-t)/(1097-1006))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+8)-p}} 
else if(t<1188){t <- ((1188-t)/(1188-1097))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+7)-p}}
else if(t<1280){t <- ((1280-t)/(1280-1188))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+6)-p}}
else if(t<1371){t <- ((1371-t)/(1371-1280)) 
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+5)-p}}
else if(t<1461){t <- ((1461-t)/(1461-1371))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+4)-p}}
else if(t<1553){t <- ((1553-t)/(1553-1461)) 
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+3)-p}}
else if(t<1645){t <- ((1645-t)/(1645-1553))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+2)-p}}
else if(t<1736){t <- ((1736-t)/(1736-1645))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t)+(N+c)/((1+(ytc/f)))^(t+1)-p}}  
else if(t<1826){t<-((1826-t)/(1826-1736))
q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){(N+c)/(1+(ytc/f))^(t)-p}} 
else q <- function(ytc,p,c,t=0,f=4,N=100){((N+c)/p)-((ytc/f))-1} 

q2<- function(ytc){q(ytc,p,c,t,N=100)}
yield.t.c <- uniroot(q2,c(-1,10),tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)$root 
return(yield.t.c)
}
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(Datum = structure(c(17960, 17961, 17962, 17963, 
17966, 17967), class = "Date"), `CoCo-Preis` = c(98.19, 98.14, 
98.21, 97.97, 98.01, 98.03), `CDS-Spread` = c(55.67, 55.23, 55.64, 
56.27, 55.05, 53.33), Aktienpreis = c(4.244, 4.3145, 4.163, 4.0785, 
4.1375, 4.142), Zins = c(-0.287467, -0.31443, -0.360349, -0.351772, 
-0.363637, -0.36096), t = c(1819L, 1820L, 1821L, 1822L, 1825L, 
1826L)), row.names = 1260:1265, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages when it stops at 1264?

Comment: No. It seems to print the same value as for i=1264 into the table. The value should be like 0.133 but is 1 which is equal to the value of the 1294 i.

Comment: But this is then adjusted by the second code. Don't know why but it works. I am only wondering what causes this in the first code.

Comment: `c(1, 1265)` has two elements; `1:1265` has 1265 elements.  Is that the issue?

Comment: @Leon, and at the end of the first for loop, your value for `i` is `1264L`? That's very strange... Do you have some sample code we can reproduce this with?

Comment: @user2554330 when I insert the vector in the loop he is going to insert all values from 1 to 1265 so I don't understand why it only has too elements then? I thought it is simply another way to express the interval

Comment: @sven what do you mean by sample code? Do you mean data?

Comment: @user2554330 Now I see what you mean! In the second code he is only adding the value for i=1265 then. okay I understand... But why is he then not going up to that i=1265 in the first equation?

Comment: @Leon, sorry yes, I meant sample data.

Comment: @sven How can I provide my data?

Comment: Post the output of `dput(data)` or if that's too big, `dput(head(data))` for each of the data pieces we would need. In this case I suppose we only need it for `timeseries1`.

Comment: @Sven Is there a way to post the last values only? Because that are the interesting ones for the function.

Comment: Sure, use tail instead of head.

Comment: added the function and will add the data in a second

Comment: Okay and it seems as if the data type was not the problem. I don't get it why the first code of the loop does not add my last value of i=1265 correctly.

Comment: The problem is with your `uniroot` function. it seems when there isn't a root at that interval, your loop stops. You can try to allow the function to extend the interval with `yield.t.c <- uniroot(q2,c(-1,10),tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5, extendInt = "yes")$root `. It works for me then.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you!

Comment: Hooo... that's heck of a function. You may be interested in opening a new question asking for help writing a nicer version of the function---one that is readable and has much lower probability of a unnoticed typo causing a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reproducing, it seems the loop stops at the 2nd but last iteration of the loop, hence your `i` being stuck at `1264L` or in the sample data at the 5th iteration. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961221/uniroot-solution-in-r)
it was clear that the problem is with the intervals of the `uniroot` function. As per the suggestion in that link, it worked for me when adding the `extendInt = "yes"` to the line.

```
yield.t.c <- uniroot(q2,c(-1,10),tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5, extendInt = "yes")$root
```

Hope it helps!